# Adjust the position of the button dynamically when StackPanel exceeds certain width

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer, stackpanel

I need to adjust the position of a button inside a grid which has a stack panel inside a srollviewer, such a way that whenever the scroll bar appears it should be at the end and when ScrollBar is not available it should be next to the last item.

[With Horizontal Scroll Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c61wH.png) , as expected but in
[Without Horizontal scroll Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0q4nM.png) there is a gap between button and last textbox. How can I get rid of this gap without affecting the [With Horizontal Scroll Bar] behaviour.

Here is the code snippet used :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"  />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="6"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox Text="TextBox1" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Text="TextBox2" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Text="TextBox3" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Text="TextBox4" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Text="TextBox5" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Text="TextBox6" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <Button Content="Button" Grid.Column="2"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: With your current XAML. the button will always stay next to ScrollViewer horizontally. So what do you want to achieve ? it's unclear ..can you show some image ?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0q4nM.png in this image there is a gap between the last text box and the button. I want to get rid of that gap. I tried making width of the stackpanel as auto but that didnt help.

Comment: that's because of this `<ColumnDefinition Width="6"/>`

Comment: this middle column is taking the space. You can remove it or rather make it's width `Auto`

Comment: Actually the text-boxes are added dynamically inside stack panel. I dont have control how many text boxes are added. In the sample code i posted it has only 6. When the number of text boxes increase the button disappears if i keep width as Auto. If i make it as * then, if number of text boxes decrease to 1/2 then again the gap appears (without extra column definition )

Comment: You said you want to remove the SPACE between Button and ScrollViewer. And i told you that if you remove that middle column then that space will not be there anymore

Comment: so what else you want ?

Comment: The problem here is that when the content of the stackpanel is less( number of text boxes is less), the scrollviewer width still remains same . Hence visually there will be a blank space between Last Textbox and the button. Is thre any suggestion where when the size of stack panel reduces automatically the size of the scroll view gets reduced

Comment: Yes it's easy ! `<ColumnDefinition Width="5*"  />` this is your first column which contains Scroll Viewer. You just need to make it's width to `auto`  `<ColumnDefinition Width="auto"  />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you want (sticky behavior). Just make a few changes in XAML like this.

```
<Grid x:Name="ParentGrid">
    <Grid Grid.Column="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"  />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <TextBox Text="TextBox1" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox Text="TextBox2" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox Text="TextBox3" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox Text="TextBox4" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox Text="TextBox5" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox Text="TextBox6" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox Text="TextBox6" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox Text="TextBox6" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox Text="TextBox6" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox Text="TextBox6" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox Text="TextBox6" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox Text="TextBox6" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox Text="TextBox6" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox Text="TextBox6" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox Text="TextBox6" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox Text="TextBox6" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox Text="TextBox6" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox Text="TextBox6" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>

                    <TextBox Text="TextBox6" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>

        
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
            <Button Content="Button" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

It works completely fine.

[image: Demo gif]

Comment: Thank for reply but with this when the content of stack panel grows, the button will be hidden and horizontal scroll bar never appears since the width is Auto.

Comment: @Developer123 please check the updated answer. It works perfectly.. I had to try a lot for you :)